Aging distribution by location using receipt transactions
I have a stock query which gives the stock available for a particular item by location:

Another query gives all the receipts by quantity, date and receipt txn and number for the same item in descending order:

We want an output like below using a SQL Query:

I want to add the receipt details (transaction code, number, quantity and date) for each location stock available and distribute it as per the receipt quantity comparing the available stock. The receipt details and quantity goes in loop until the total matches the stock quantity and then it takes the next receipt and loops until all the location quantities are matched with the receipts.
Kindly I need your expertise in solving this issue. Thanks.
Query to create the Stock Table and insert data:
    CREATE TABLE STOCK
(
  LCS_ITEM_CODE  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)              NOT NULL,
  LCS_LOCN_CODE  VARCHAR2(12 BYTE)              NOT NULL,
  ITEM_UOM_CODE  VARCHAR2(12 BYTE),
  STOCK_QTY      NUMBER,
  STOCKROWNUM    NUMBER
);



SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A001', 'PCS', 2280, 1);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 205, 2);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A003', 'PCS', 188, 3);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A004', 'PCS', 111, 4);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A005', 'PCS', 104, 5);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A006', 'PCS', 99, 6);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A007', 'PCS', 98, 7);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A008', 'PCS', 88, 8);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A009', 'PCS', 71, 9);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A010', 'PCS', 65, 10);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A011', 'PCS', 60, 11);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A012', 'PCS', 56, 12);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A013', 'PCS', 46, 13);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A014', 'PCS', 24, 14);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A015', 'PCS', 13, 15);
Insert into STOCK
   (LCS_ITEM_CODE, LCS_LOCN_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, STOCK_QTY, STOCKROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'A016', 'PCS', 5, 16);
COMMIT;

Query to create the receipts table and data:
CREATE TABLE RECEIPT
(
  SL_ITEM_CODE   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  ITEM_UOM_CODE  VARCHAR2(12 BYTE),
  SL_TXN_CODE    VARCHAR2(12 BYTE),
  SL_NO          NUMBER(10),
  SL_CONF_DT     DATE,
  SL_QTY         NUMBER,
  RECEIPTROWNUM  NUMBER
);

SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2024000375, TO_DATE('07/30/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    3000, 1);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2024000200, TO_DATE('04/06/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    4000, 2);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2022999987, TO_DATE('11/24/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    8000, 3);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2022000084, TO_DATE('02/09/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    2500, 4);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2021000389, TO_DATE('09/10/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    2000, 5);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2021000001, TO_DATE('12/08/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    3500, 6);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2020000179, TO_DATE('06/23/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    3500, 7);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2019999995, TO_DATE('11/30/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    3000, 8);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2018999998, TO_DATE('12/18/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    1000, 9);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2018000042, TO_DATE('01/12/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    6000, 10);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2017000171, TO_DATE('07/05/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    4500, 11);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2017000001, TO_DATE('01/19/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    2000, 12);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2016000071, TO_DATE('03/30/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    3500, 13);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2015000177, TO_DATE('07/01/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    1000, 14);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2015000026, TO_DATE('01/09/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    3000, 15);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2014000117, TO_DATE('04/22/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    1000, 16);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2013000174, TO_DATE('08/30/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    2000, 17);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2013000022, TO_DATE('01/09/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    2000, 18);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2012000313, TO_DATE('08/16/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    2000, 19);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2012000089, TO_DATE('03/01/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    2000, 20);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2012000090, TO_DATE('02/24/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    40, 21);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2011000243, TO_DATE('08/20/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    1960, 22);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2011000131, TO_DATE('05/12/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    500, 23);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2011000049, TO_DATE('02/11/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    2000, 24);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2010000223, TO_DATE('08/05/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    500, 25);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2010000135, TO_DATE('05/08/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    500, 26);
Insert into RECEIPT
   (SL_ITEM_CODE, ITEM_UOM_CODE, SL_TXN_CODE, SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, 
    SL_QTY, RECEIPTROWNUM)
 Values
   ('AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2009000133, TO_DATE('06/11/2020 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    4000, 27);
COMMIT;

The stock query:
SELECT LCS_ITEM_CODE,LCS_LOCN_CODE,ITEM_UOM_CODE,STOCK, STOCKROWNUM FROM STOCK

The receipt query:
Select SL_ITEM_CODE,ITEM_UOM_CODE,SL_TXN_CODE,SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, SL_QTY,RECEIPTROWNUM FROM RECEIPT;

I have tried using cursors and temporary table , this is how far I was able to go but doesn't give the desired result:
Query to create temporary table:
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_results (
LCS_ITEM_CODE VARCHAR2(50),
LCS_LOCN_CODE VARCHAR2(50),
ITEM_UOM_CODE VARCHAR2(50),
STOCK_QTY NUMBER,
SL_TXN_CODE VARCHAR2(50),
SL_NO VARCHAR2(50),
SL_CONF_DT DATE,
SL_QTY NUMBER,
BALANCE NUMBER
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

The cursor query:
DECLARE
   TYPE stock_rec_type
   IS
      RECORD (
         LCS_ITEM_CODE   os_locn_curr_stk.lcs_item_code%TYPE,
         LCS_LOCN_CODE   os_locn_curr_stk.lcs_locn_code%TYPE,
         ITEM_UOM_CODE   om_item_uom.iu_uom_code%TYPE,
         STOCK_QTY       NUMBER,
         STOCKROWNUM     NUMBER
      );
   TYPE receipt_rec_type
   IS
      RECORD (
         SL_ITEM_CODE    os_stk_ledger.sl_item_code%TYPE,
         ITEM_UOM_CODE   om_item_uom.iu_uom_code%TYPE,
         SL_TXN_CODE     os_stk_ledger.sl_txn_code%TYPE,
         SL_NO           os_stk_ledger.sl_no%TYPE,
         SL_CONF_DT      DATE,
         SL_QTY          NUMBER,
         RECEIPTROWNUM   NUMBER
      );
   CURSOR stock_cur
   IS
      SELECT LCS_ITEM_CODE,LCS_LOCN_CODE,ITEM_UOM_CODE,STOCK, STOCKROWNUM FROM STOCK;
   CURSOR receipt_cur
   IS
       Select SL_ITEM_CODE,ITEM_UOM_CODE,SL_TXN_CODE,SL_NO, SL_CONF_DT, SL_QTY,RECEIPTROWNUM FROM RECEIPT;
   stock_rec      stock_rec_type;
   receipt_rec    receipt_rec_type;
   balance        NUMBER;
   temp_balance   NUMBER;
BEGIN

balance:=0;
 OPEN receipt_cur;
   FETCH receipt_cur INTO   receipt_rec;
   WHILE receipt_cur%FOUND --AND balance<=0--
   LOOP                                                                     --
balance := receipt_rec.SL_QTY-balance;
  
     OPEN stock_cur;
      FETCH stock_cur INTO   stock_rec;
      WHILE stock_cur%FOUND
      LOOP
            balance :=  balance-stock_rec.STOCK_QTY;
         if balance<0 THEN 
         FETCH receipt_cur INTO   receipt_rec;
         ELSE
         INSERT INTO temp_results
           VALUES   (stock_rec.LCS_ITEM_CODE,
                     stock_rec.LCS_LOCN_CODE,
                     stock_rec.ITEM_UOM_CODE,
                     stock_rec.STOCK_QTY,
                     receipt_rec.SL_TXN_CODE,
                     receipt_rec.SL_NO,
                     receipt_rec.SL_CONF_DT,
                     receipt_rec.SL_QTY,
                     balance);
END IF;
--if balance<0 THEN
--balance:=99;
-- END IF;
     FETCH stock_cur INTO   stock_rec;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE stock_cur;
      FETCH receipt_cur INTO   receipt_rec;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE receipt_cur;

END;
/
SELECT   * FROM temp_results;


Calculate the running totals for the stock and receipt and then join on thse running totals:
WITH total_stock (
  LCS_ITEM_CODE,
  LCS_LOCN_CODE,
  ITEM_UOM_CODE,
  STOCK_QTY,
  STOCKROWNUM,
  TOTAL_STOCK_QTY,
  PREV_TOTAL_STOCK_QTY
) AS (
  SELECT s.*,
         SUM(stock_qty) OVER (PARTITION BY lcs_item_code, item_uom_code ORDER BY stockrownum),
         SUM(stock_qty) OVER (PARTITION BY lcs_item_code, item_uom_code ORDER BY stockrownum) - stock_qty
  FROM   stock s
),
total_receipts (
  SL_ITEM_CODE,
  ITEM_UOM_CODE,
  SL_TXN_CODE,
  SL_NO,
  SL_CONF_DT,
  SL_QTY,
  RECEIPTROWNUM,
  TOTAL_SL_QTY,
  PREV_TOTAL_SL_QTY
) AS (
  SELECT r.*,
         SUM(sl_qty) OVER (PARTITION BY sl_item_code, item_uom_code ORDER BY receiptrownum),
         SUM(sl_qty) OVER (PARTITION BY sl_item_code, item_uom_code ORDER BY receiptrownum) - sl_qty
  FROM   receipt r
)
SELECT s.lcs_item_code,
       s.lcs_locn_code,
       s.item_uom_code,
       LEAST(s.total_stock_qty, r.total_sl_qty)
       - GREATEST(s.prev_total_stock_qty, r.prev_total_sl_qty) AS stock_qty,
       r.sl_txn_code,
       r.sl_no,
       r.sl_conf_dt,
       r.sl_qty,
       GREATEST(r.total_sl_qty - s.total_stock_qty, 0) AS balance
FROM   total_stock s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN total_receipts r
       ON     s.lcs_item_code = r.sl_item_code
          AND s.item_uom_code = r.item_uom_code
          AND s.total_stock_qty > r.prev_total_sl_qty
          AND s.prev_total_stock_qty < r.total_sl_qty
ORDER BY
       s.lcs_item_code,
       s.item_uom_code,
       s.stockrownum;

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



LCS_ITEM_CODE
LCS_LOCN_COD
ITEM_UOM_COD
STOCK_QTY
SL_TXN_CODE
SL_NO
SL_CONF_DT
SL_QTY
BALANCE




AMZ_BSCS
A001
PCS
2280
RECP
2024000375
2020-07-30 00:00:00
3000
720


AMZ_BSCS
A002
PCS
205
RECP
2024000375
2020-07-30 00:00:00
3000
515


AMZ_BSCS
A003
PCS
188
RECP
2024000375
2020-07-30 00:00:00
3000
327


AMZ_BSCS
A004
PCS
111
RECP
2024000375
2020-07-30 00:00:00
3000
216


AMZ_BSCS
A005
PCS
104
RECP
2024000375
2020-07-30 00:00:00
3000
112


AMZ_BSCS
A006
PCS
99
RECP
2024000375
2020-07-30 00:00:00
3000
13


AMZ_BSCS
A007
PCS
13
RECP
2024000375
2020-07-30 00:00:00
3000
0


AMZ_BSCS
A007
PCS
85
RECP
2024000200
2020-04-06 00:00:00
4000
3915


AMZ_BSCS
A008
PCS
88
RECP
2024000200
2020-04-06 00:00:00
4000
3827


AMZ_BSCS
A009
PCS
71
RECP
2024000200
2020-04-06 00:00:00
4000
3756


AMZ_BSCS
A010
PCS
65
RECP
2024000200
2020-04-06 00:00:00
4000
3691


AMZ_BSCS
A011
PCS
60
RECP
2024000200
2020-04-06 00:00:00
4000
3631


AMZ_BSCS
A012
PCS
56
RECP
2024000200
2020-04-06 00:00:00
4000
3575


AMZ_BSCS
A013
PCS
46
RECP
2024000200
2020-04-06 00:00:00
4000
3529


AMZ_BSCS
A014
PCS
24
RECP
2024000200
2020-04-06 00:00:00
4000
3505


AMZ_BSCS
A015
PCS
13
RECP
2024000200
2020-04-06 00:00:00
4000
3492


AMZ_BSCS
A016
PCS
5
RECP
2024000200
2020-04-06 00:00:00
4000
3487



fiddle

@MTO , the record A007 is breaking up into 2 records which is as desired but the stock_qty should distribute as per the remaining balance from the receipt in the first row and the remaining stock in the next row.

@syedcic Updated

THANKS @mto, it works fine in the fiddle but doesn't work on my oracle db because my version is 11gR2 and the fiddle is 23ai I think.

I converted it into a sql query to run on my db and it is working but if the stock is in one record and receipts in multiple records, it doesn't gives the correct output. In fiddle it shows 8 records as output but in oracle only 4 records

@syedcic Please provide a [MRE] that replicates the issue.

The code should work on Oracle 11g - unfortunately the 11g fiddle is broken at the moment so I cannot test it. It works on Oracle 18 fiddle.

@MTO, thanks the query worked. The problem was in my data but the query behaves weird if the receipt date is same for the next receipt.  There are cases we saw same day multiple receipts were recieved with same quantities.

A first attempt:
with stock(item_code, locn_code, item_uom, stock, rn) as (
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A001', 'PCS', 2280, 1 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 205, 2 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 188, 3 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 111, 4 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 104, 5 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 99, 6  from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 98, 7  from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 88, 8  from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 71, 9  from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 65, 10  from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 60, 11  from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 56, 12  from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 46, 13  from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 24, 14  from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 13, 15  from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'A002', 'PCS', 5, 16 --  from dual union all
),
receipts(item_code, uom_code, txn_code, no, conf_dt, qty, rn) as (
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2024000375, date '2024-07-30', 3000, 1 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2024000200, date '2024-04-06', 4000, 2 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2022999987, date '2024-04-06', 8000, 3 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2022000084, date '2024-04-06', 2500, 4 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2021000389, date '2024-04-06', 2000, 5 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2021000001, date '2024-04-06', 3500, 6 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2020000179, date '2024-04-06', 3500, 7 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2019999995, date '2024-04-06', 3000, 8 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2018999998, date '2024-04-06', 1000, 9 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2010000042, date '2024-04-06', 6000, 10 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2017000171, date '2024-04-06', 4500, 11 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2017000001, date '2024-04-06', 2000, 12 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2016000071, date '2024-04-06', 3500, 13 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2015000177, date '2024-04-06', 1000, 14 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2015000026, date '2024-04-06', 3000, 15 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2014000117, date '2024-04-06', 1000, 16 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2013000174, date '2024-04-06', 2000, 17 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2013000022, date '2024-04-06', 2000, 18 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2012000313, date '2024-04-06', 2000, 19 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2012000089, date '2024-04-06', 2000, 20 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2012000090, date '2024-04-06', 40, 21 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2011000243, date '2024-04-06', 1960, 22 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2011000131, date '2024-04-06', 500, 23 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2011000049, date '2024-04-06', 2000, 24 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2010000223, date '2024-04-06', 500, 25 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2010000135, date '2024-04-06', 500, 26 from dual union all
    select 'AMZ_BSCS', 'PCS', 'RECP', 2009000133, date '2024-04-06', 4000, 27 -- from dual union all
),
cstock(item_code, locn_code, item_uom, stock, rn, cum_stock) as (
    select item_code, locn_code, item_uom, stock, rn, 
        sum(stock) over(partition by item_code order by rn) 
    from stock stk
),
creceipts(item_code, uom_code, txn_code, no, conf_dt, qty, rn, cum_qty) as (
    select item_code, uom_code, txn_code, no, conf_dt, qty, rn,
        sum(qty) over(partition by item_code order by rn) 
    from receipts
),
cte(
    item_code, uom_code, txn_code, locn_code, no, conf_dt, qty, rn, stock, stk_rn,
    report, balance,
    priority, cnt
) as (
    select rcp.item_code, rcp.uom_code, rcp.txn_code, stk.locn_code, rcp.no, 
        rcp.conf_dt, rcp.qty, rcp.rn, 
        stk.stock, stk.rn as stk_rn,
        least(rcp.qty - stk.stock, 0) as report,
        greatest(rcp.qty - stk.stock, 0) as balance,
        1, 1
    from creceipts rcp
    join cstock stk on rcp.item_code = stk.item_code and rcp.rn = stk.rn
    where rcp.rn = 1
    
    union all
    
    select 
        case when r.balance - rcp.stock > 0 
            then case when rcp.priority = 0 and rcp.cnt > 1 then null else r.item_code end 
            else case when rcp.priority = 0 and rcp.cnt > 1 then r.item_code else null end
        end,
        rcp.uom_code, rcp.txn_code, rcp.locn_code,  
        rcp.no, 
        rcp.conf_dt, rcp.qty, rcp.rn,   
        case when least(r.balance - rcp.stock, 0) < 0 then -least(r.balance - rcp.stock, 0) else rcp.stock end, 
        rcp.stk_rn, 
        - least(r.balance - rcp.stock, 0), 
        case when least(r.balance - rcp.stock, 0) < 0 
            then rcp.qty + least(r.balance - rcp.stock, 0) 
            else greatest(r.balance - rcp.stock, 0)
        end,
        rcp.priority, rcp.cnt
    from cte r,
    lateral (
        select 
            count(distinct no) over() as cnt, 
            case when rcp.rn = r.rn then 1 else 0 end as priority,
            rcp.item_code, rcp.uom_code, rcp.txn_code, stk.locn_code, rcp.no, rcp.conf_dt, rcp.qty, rcp.rn, rcp.cum_qty,
            stk.stock, stk.cum_stock, stk.rn as stk_rn
        from creceipts rcp 
        join cstock stk on rcp.item_code = stk.item_code
        
        where r.item_code = rcp.item_code -- and r.balance - stk.stock > 0
        and (
            (rcp.rn = r.rn or rcp.rn = r.rn + 1)
            and r.stk_rn + 1 = stk.rn
        ) 
    ) rcp 
)
cycle item_code, rn, stk_rn set is_loop to 'Y' default 'N'
select item_code, uom_code, txn_code, locn_code, stock, no, conf_dt, qty, balance
from cte
where item_code is not null
;

Note that the line
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    13  2024000375  30/07/24    3000    0

is not in the result yet, not only because it's annoying to generate but also because it then takes part to the recursion and a safe way to avoid that has to be defined.
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A001    2280    2024000375  30/07/24    3000    720
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    205     2024000375  30/07/24    3000    515
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    188     2024000375  30/07/24    3000    327
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    111     2024000375  30/07/24    3000    216
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    104     2024000375  30/07/24    3000    112
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    99      2024000375  30/07/24    3000    13
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    85      2024000200  06/04/24    4000    3915
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    88      2024000200  06/04/24    4000    3827
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    71      2024000200  06/04/24    4000    3756
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    65      2024000200  06/04/24    4000    3691
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    60      2024000200  06/04/24    4000    3631
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    56      2024000200  06/04/24    4000    3575
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    46      2024000200  06/04/24    4000    3529
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    24      2024000200  06/04/24    4000    3505
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    13      2024000200  06/04/24    4000    3492
AMZ_BSCS    PCS RECP    A002    5       2024000200  06/04/24    4000    3487

